# Determining if this function is continuous using given theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Theorem:
>
> Let $f: \left ( X,d \right )\rightarrow \left ( Y,e \right )$ be a map between metric spaces. f is continuous iff for every open set $V\subseteq Y$, the pre-image $f^{-1}\left ( V \right )\subseteq$ X is open.
>
> Question:
> Use the above theorem to show that $f\left ( x \right )=2x$ is continuous and that $sgn\left ( x \right )$ is not continuous.

I am having a bit of difficulty determining what the proper subset V in either case is. If someone would kindly show me how I can utilise the above theorem with the first part, I believe I can use it to understand the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you did not specify the domain and range of your functions. I will assume the domain and range are both **R**, with the standard metric.

The theorem says that to check whether $f$ is continuous on **R**, you must check whether *every* open subset of **R** (the range) pulls back to another open subset of **R** (the domain) through the inverse image of $f$. So it is not a matter of finding the "proper" V: the theorem says you need to check them all!

Obviously this is impossible to do directly, for there are uncountably many open subsets of **R**. So this theorem is not so useful after all. Instead, you want to use a slightly but equivalent theorem that says $f$ is continuous so long as the inverse image of every open interval of the form $(a,b)$ is open. Why is this equivalent to your theorem? Because the open intervals $(a,b)$ form a basis for the topology of **R**.

Now, we just need to look at the inverse image of $(a,b)$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume we are working with the standard Euclidean topology, and that both functions are maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. The open sets in $\mathbb R$ that we have to consider are then $(a, b)$, with $a, b \in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ and $a < b$ (we could, in theory, consider even less sets, i.e. those in the form $(-a, a)$).

If $a$ and $b$ are real it's easy to show that $f^{-1}((a, b)) = (a/2, 
b/2)$, since $f$ is a bijection. It remains to show that the other three cases result in open sets, which is fairly straightforward, as
$$\begin{align}
f^{-1}((-\infty, +\infty)) &= \mathbb R\qquad\qquad\text{(open by definition)}\\
f^{-1}((-\infty, b)) &= (-\infty, b/2)\\
f^{-1}((a, +\infty)) &= (a/2, +\infty)
\end{align}$$

For the second part, it is sufficient to find *one* open set the pre-image of which is not open. For example, $\operatorname{sign}^{-1}(-0.5, 0.5) = \{0\}$, which is a closed set since all metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces.

---

Note: I approached the problem from a topological point of view. Since you didn't mention topology, you'll have to do a little more work to show that those are indeed open sets.